# std::scoped_allocator_adaptor and a class with a constructor using std::allocator_arg_t

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, allocator

I find some words here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/scoped_allocator_adaptor/construct

> if `std::uses_allocator<T, inner_allocator_type>::value==true` (the type
>   T uses allocators, e.g. it is a container)
>
> and if
>   `std::is_constructible<T, std::allocator_arg_t, inner_allocator_type, Args...>::value==true`,
>
> then calls
>
> ```
> std::allocator_traits<OUTERMOST>::construct( OUTERMOST(*this),
>                                              p,
>                                              std::allocator_arg,
>                                              inner_allocator(),
>                                              std::forward<Args>(args)... );
> ```

So, I do a simple test

```
struct use_arg {
    template <typename Alloc>
    use_arg(std::allocator_arg_t, Alloc &, int i)
        { std::cout << i << " in use_arg()\n"; }
};

namespace std {

template <typename A> struct uses_allocator<use_arg, A>: true_type {};

} // namespace std

void test_scoped()
{
    std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<use_arg>> sa;
    auto p = sa.allocate(1);
    sa.construct(p, 4);
    sa.destroy(p);
    sa.deallocate(p, 1);
}
```

but gcc and clang give me these errors https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e72754a7615162280fb

I also write `use_a` to replace `use_arg`. It could run successfully.

```
struct use_a {
    template <typename Alloc>
    use_a(int i, Alloc &) { std::cout << i << " in use_a()\n"; }
};
```

What makes these behaviors happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think both libstdc++ and libc++ are doing exactly what the standard requires for the OP's example.

`uses_allocator<use_arg, allocator<use_arg>>` is true, but `is_constructible<use_arg, allocator_arg_t, inner_allocator_type, int>` is false because `use_arg` is not constructible from an rvalue allocator, so the `construct` call should be ill-formed.

However, I think it's a defect in the standard. Consider this type:

```
struct use_arg {
  using allocator_type = std::allocator<use_arg>;
  use_arg(allocator_type&&) { }
};
```

The `uses_allocator` and `is_constructible` traits are both true, but calls to `scoped_allocator_adaptor::construct(pointer)` will fail to compile.

It is inconsistent to check `is_constructible<T, inner_allocator_type>` (which tests for construction from an rvalue allocator) but then pass `inner_allocator_type&` (which is an lvalue), but that's what the standard says.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that you receives `Alloc` by reference.

```
std::is_constructible<T, std::allocator_arg_t, inner_allocator_type, Args...>::value==true
```

here in your case `inner_allocator` is just `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<use_arg>>`
and it cannot be converted to `std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<use_arg>>&`. You can just receives `Alloc` by value, or by `const-reference`.

Comment: What about `std::is_constructible<use_a, int,std::scoped_allocator_adaptor<std::allocator<use_a>>>::value`? It's also `false` but could construct.

Comment: @linux40 that looks like a bug, since for example in clang, there is no this check, only uses_allocator::value is checked.

Comment: there is only one check in gcc also.

Comment: @ForEveR, what do you mean "there is only one check in gcc"? See line 85 in `<bits/uses_allocator.h>` for the `is_constructible` check and line 96 for the `uses_allocator` check.

Comment: Oh, you mean only `is_constructible<T, allocator_arg_t, A, Args...>` is checked, and not `is_constructible<T, Args..., A>`, right? The second check is redundant, because if it is false then attempting to do that construction would be ill-formed, as required by the standard. The problem is that the standard is defective and requires that a _different_ construction gets done, which _isn't_ ill-formed.